# An infinite-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ not equal to $\mathbb{R}^\infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples

> Let $V=\mathbb{R}^\infty$  be be the vector space of real-valued sequences. Does
>   there exist an infinite-dimensional subspace $U \subseteq V$ such that $U$ is not equal to $V$?

I'm not even sure where to start with this one and a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One remark to your notation: it is very common in mathematics to denote by $\Bbb R^\infty$ the space of sequences that only contain finitely many nonzero elements (at least in topology). The space of all real-valued sequences I rather would denote by $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$. But it hasn't any impact here.

Comment: The notation was not provided by me, nor is it particularly familiar to me, but thank you for the information :)

Answer (score 4):

Given a natural number $n$, we can consider the subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by
$$U=\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:a_1=0\}$$
You should know (and be able to prove) that $\dim(U)=n-1$.

However, if $n$ were not a natural number, but instead $\infty$...

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm quite on the same page as you yet. Do you mean to imply that if V has infinite dimension, we can consider subspace U of infinite size and from there reach the idea that U has infinite dimension?

Comment: I'm suggesting that the subspace
$$U=\{(a_1,a_2,\ldots)\in\mathbb{R}^\infty:a_1=0\}$$
of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is infinite-dimensional. I don't see what you mean by "size" though - if you mean cardinality (i.e., how many elements are in the set), that's not relevant to the issue of dimension for this problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you. How might I relate this to the problem of whether U=V?

Comment: There are sequences of real numbers that *don't* start with $0$. So the set of sequences of real numbers that *do* start with $0$ can't be all of them...

Answer (score 1):

Abstract solution valid for any infinite dimensional space: let be $B$ a basis of $V$. Any infinite proper subset of $B$ spans an infinite dimensional subspace $U$ with $U\ne V$.

Answer (score -1):

There are several [sequence spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space) which are quite natural and some of them are quite important in functional analysis.

I will mention just two examples:

- The spaces $c_0$ consisting of all sequences convergent to zero (i.e., all null sequences).
- The space $c_{00}$ consisting of all sequences which have only finitely many non-zero terms. (They are also called sequences with finite support or eventually constant sequences.) You may notice that this is exactly the span of the vectors $e^{i}$, $i\in\mathbb N$, where $e^i$ denotes the sequence which has one on $i$-th coordinate and all other coordinates are zeroes. So, in a sense, this reminds generating $\mathbb R^n$ using standard basis.

It should not be difficult to show that both $c_0$ and $c_{00}$ are infinite-dimensional proper subspaces of what you denote $\mathbb R^\infty$. (For some reasons my personal preference is the notation $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. You can see in some [other posts on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%5Cmathbb+R%5E%7B%5Cmathbb+N%7D%22) that it is not entirely uncommon notation. This notation has already been mentioned in [Peter Franek's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150330/an-infinite-dimensional-subspace-of-mathbbr-infty-not-equal-to-mathbbr/2175608#comment4422968_2150330). Some people also use [the notation $\mathbb R^\omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%5Cmathbb+R%5E%7B%5Comega%7D%22).)

Basically any sequence space from the the Wikipedia article I linked above should work. (With the caveat that in that article sometimes $\mathbb C$ is used as the base field, so you are interested only in real case.) I have chosen two examples which seemed to be relatively simple and also somewhat natural.